# S3 trigger sending bulk upload notification to AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, eventtrigger

I want to execute two lambda function when a new object uploaded on s3.
I am using s3 trigger at bucket level and sending notifications to AWS SNS, 2 lambda functions have subscribe to these SNS to get notifications.

I tried uploading 100 files and I could see all file name got printed in log in both function.
But in one function I could see 2 logs where as in another I could see 3 logs when combined I can see name of all 100 files.

How SNS works if it gets too many object upload notification ?

How Lambda function works, for e.g let's say its still processing the first file and it gets notification to process second file and third file

Is there a chance of few files getting skipped by Lambda because it received too many notification

Comment: This could be related to Lambda timeout and re-try - what are your lambda functions doing with this notification & the files that are uploaded?

Comment: See:  [Error Handling and Automatic Retries in AWS Lambda - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html) and [AWS Lambda Function Scaling - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html)

Comment: I assume "when combined I can see name of all 100 files" refers to combining the logs from each function, per function; i.e. not combining all 5 logs. In that case this is perfectly normal. Lambda will have started up multiple instances of the function due to the rate of notifications received. In one case it started up 2 instances, in the other 3. Each instance writes to its own log stream.